# Square root in cases environment causes letters to be cut off

Tags: align, cases

I'm writing an equation in the cases environment that looks like:

```
\begin{align}
B = 
    \begin{cases}
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0}\dfrac{x}{a}, & \text{if $x < a$} \\
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0},             & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

But the $T_0$ ends up overlapping the square root (see attached image). Is there a way to make the square root larger so this doesn't happen?

[image]

Comment: What is your minimal working example?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you've posted -- specifically, I cannot get the horizontal stroke of the uppercase-letter `T` touch the horizontal rule above the argument of the second square root term -- if I make your code snippet minimally compilable and employ the `article` document class. Do please tell us more about your document setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `dcases` from `mathtools`.

I also make a few suggestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for dcases

\begin{document}

You should never use \texttt{align} for a single equation
\begin{equation}
B = 
    \begin{cases}
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0}\dfrac{x}{a}, & \text{if $x < a$} \\
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0},             & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Let's see what happens with \texttt{dcases}
\begin{equation}
B = 
    \begin{dcases}
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0}\frac{x}{a}, & \text{if $x < a$} \\
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0},             & \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
and with a finishing touch
\begin{equation}
B = 
    \begin{dcases}
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0}\,\frac{x}{a}, & \text{if $x < a$} \\
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0},             & \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
or, possibly better
\begin{equation}
B = 
    \begin{dcases}
        2\,\frac{x}{a}\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0}, & \text{if $x < a$} \\
        2\sqrt{\mu_0 T_0 n_0},             & \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be using `\strut` for the `\sqrt` increasing the height of the root.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{cases}
        2\sqrt{\strut \mu_0 T_0 n_0}\,\dfrac{x}{a}, & \text{if $x < a$}\\
        2\sqrt{\strut \mu_0 T_0 n_0},             & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]